# Conditonal Formatting if cell A is within a range of numbers to make cell B a different color

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I am looking to create a conditional format that if a cell "A" is within a range of two numbers that cell "B" will then change color in Google Sheets. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for a number between **`1.9`** - **`8.1`**
- custom formula applied for cell **B1** or range **B1:B**

  ```
  =($A1>=2)*($A1<=8)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thats it!  Thank you very much.